# Couldnt't import Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am new to Django and I get this error while setting up.

> Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "available on
>   your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "forget to activate a
>   virtual environment?" in the manage.py file.

I have created a virtual environment and activated using "env1/Scripts/activate".

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'health.settings')
        try:
            from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
        except ImportError as exc:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            ) from exc
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: what packages are installed in the virtual environment? What is the output of `pip freeze` *after* you enabled the virtual environment?

Comment: in command with venv active line try importing django to see if its installed correctly. ```>>>import django
>>> django.VERSION```

Comment: Pip freeze gives me this output- Django==2.1.1
pytz==2018.5

Comment: try python shell ! what error you get ?

Comment: when I run manage.py it throws this "ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?"

Comment: Are you using `virtualenv` or `venv` for setting up your project environment? And if so then what is your operating system, is it Linux, Mac or Windows?